# Project builds, until Swashbuckle is installed, and then "Could not load file or assembly" error

Tags: .net, sharepoint, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a solution with 25 projects in it.  The start up project is a web service, built on MVC 5, C#, .NET 4.5.1.

The solution builds and runs fine locally.  I want to build a Swagger specification for the web service, so I installed Swashbuckle 5.5.3.  I then run the code and now it errors out.  The only change is I am simply adding Swashbuckle via NuGet.

The error is, `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.`

I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime in three of the 25 projects, however I'm referencing version 15.0.0.0, not version 14.0.0.0.  I have no references to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.

Steps I've taken to troubleshoot:

- Delete references to SharePoint assembilies in the three projects, re-added the references to the 15.0 version.
- Searched the solution, and .csproj files opened as XML, for references to 14.0.0.0 and found none.
- Ensured that all SharePoint references were set to copy local.
- Cleaned and rebuilt the solution.
- Tried older versions of Swashbuckle.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error, or why it only occurs after adding Swashbuckle.  I assume there is some reference which is looking for version 14.0, and not a direct reference to 14.0.  Why this error only occurs after adding Swashbuckle is a complete mystery to me.

Can anyone please provide any troubleshooting advice?

Answer (score 0):

I paid more attention to the error page.  It turns out the bin folder had a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint version 14.0.0.0.  I deleted that and then the project ran fine.

I'll update this post if or when I figure out more.  I still don't understand:

- How the reference to Microsoft.SharePoint (v. 14.0) got put in the bin folder.  The bin folder isn't checked into VSTS.
- Why the error didn't occur until I added Swashbuckle.